# Converting .mov for Davinci Resolve

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

When using Davinci Resolve, "H.264 and 265 require the paid version on Linux"

`FFMpeg` comes boxed with Ubuntu, and can be used to convert video files.  What filetype should they be converted to, and what extra arguments might one use.

---

I've tried converting to mp4, and avi but the files were still unreadable in resolve.

Comment: Changing the container doesn't necessarily change the codecs inside. +1 for the answer but you can also use Handbrake if you want a graphical app with lots of presets for pretty much everything you'll ever need.

Answer (score 6):

Based off [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBiaBYthZSo) on youtube, the recommendations are the following:

Navigate to the folder with your file, and covert with a command like so:

```
$ cd /path/to/video/folder
$ ffmpeg -i "my-video.mov" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -qscale:v 9 -vendor ap10 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -acodec pcm_s16le "my-video 2.mov"
```

I don't have details one what it's doing, but it changes the codec somehow.

Comment: it worked for me! Thanks

Comment: Same for me, perfect! Thanks!!!